# Alarm app bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, alarm

My phone is stuck in a bootloop (at least, a manual one):

1. The phone boots, and goes through the entire boot animation
2. The default alarm app goes off (before I see the home screen)
3. If I turn the alarm off, the app crashes, and then I go to a black screen.  It *does* offer to restart the app, but that does nothing.
4. If I snooze the alarm, I go to a  black screen, no crash.

I've never set an alarm on the phone.

I'm able to boot to recovery (TWRP), and I've cleared the cache, dalvik cache, and data.  I've also sideloaded a fresh image of lineage (one that I've used successfully in the past), to no avail.

I'm using a OnePlus One on Lineage 14.1 (Android 7.1).  I've really loved this phone, so I'm willing to try pretty much anything.

Comment: As an update to this question:  The next day, my phone suddenly started working.  No idea why, I didn't do a thing (besides charge it).  I'm leaving this question open in hopes that a future passerby knows what is happening and could potentially help others.